# matrix to cell matrix of indices

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, cell-array

Given a matrix of n dimensions, how can I convert it to a matrix of indices as seen below:

[image: click here]

Comment: you might need `ind2sub`?

Comment: The image is taken from the matlab documentation, wherever you find it, it should link to `ind2sub`

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by MATLAB documents, you can use `ind2sub` function:

```
IND = [3 4 5 6]
s = [3,3];
[I,J] = ind2sub(s,IND)

I =
     3     1     2     3

J =
     1     2     2     2
```

Comment: and if i don't know the number of dimensions of the matrix?

Comment: `[r,c] = size(M)` gives you the dimension of the `M` matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The function `ind2sub` should work. Another option is to calculate it by hand. This is easy. Note the stucture of the matrix. It is denoted by linear indexing distributed columnwise. This mean that the indices can be calculated as:

```
idxRow = mod(idx-1,nRows)+1;
idxCol = ceil(idx./nColumns);
```

This is more or less what is done in `ind2sub` except that function cleverly solves the problem for an N-dimensional matrix. And also have some error handling.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 3;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:n);
C = cell(n,n);
for ii = 1:n
    for jj = 1:n
        C{ii,jj} = [X(ii,jj) Y(ii,jj)];
    end
end
```

Note that the `X` and `Y` matrices are probably what you are looking for, since they are matrices. To also include the cell of indices I had to use a nested loop, but there's probably a vectorised way to do that as well.

```
X =
     1     2     3
     1     2     3
     1     2     3
Y =
     1     1     1
     2     2     2
     3     3     3
C = 
    [1x2 double]    [1x2 double]    [1x2 double]
    [1x2 double]    [1x2 double]    [1x2 double]
    [1x2 double]    [1x2 double]    [1x2 double]
```

where each `[1x2 double]` is the requested combination of indices.